# use of google sign in as both sign up and sign in both

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

i have a doubt is that how can i use google sign in method through firebase as both sign up and login .
i want to make app in which you have to first sign up through only google account to prove that given mail is true and not made up .and after signing up through google account it redirect us to next activity which contains name , adress , like  stuff.

But i want to show this second activity only once at the time of google sign up ; otherwise for login time it automatically fetch this details .

So i have a doubt that how can use this authentication service as both sign up and login.

thank you

Comment: If you are using Java, then this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. If you are using Kotlin and you are interested in using Jetpack Compose, then this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Empower Google Sign-In within the Firebase console: In the Firebase support, open the Auth section. On the Sign in strategy tab, empower the Google sign-in strategy and press Spare.